# Primefaces - update not getting triggered while hiding the dialog

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have created a simplified version of my app below.

```
    <h:form>
        <p:commandButton value="ADD NEW" action="#{sampleBean.onAddNew}" oncomplete="PF('addDialog').show()" update=":addForm"/>
    </h:form>
```

The below dialog opens when the button is clicked.

```
    <p:dialog widgetVar="addDialog">
        <h:form id="addForm">
            <p:messages autoUpdate="true" closable="true"/>
            <p:outputLabel value="Name :"/>
            <p:inputText value="#{sampleBean.name}" required="true" requiredMessage="Name is a required field"/>
            <p:outputLabel value="Address :"/>
            <p:inputText value="#{sampleBean.address}"/>
            <p:commandButton value="Save" action="#{sampleBean.save}" oncomplete="if (args &amp;&amp; !args.validationFailed) PF('addDialog').hide();"/>
            <p:commandButton value="Cancel" action="#{sampleBean.cancel}" immediate="true" oncomplete="PF('addDialog').hide()" update="addForm"/>
        </h:form>
    </p:dialog>
```

Here is the backing bean code:

```
public void onAddNew()
{
    name = "";
    address = "";
}

public void save()
{
    System.out.println("Saving ... " + name + " : " + address);
    name = "";
    address = "";
}

public void cancel()
{
    System.out.println("Cancelling ... " + name + " : " + address);
    name = "";
    address = "";
}
```

The problem i'm facing is:

If i encounter a required field validation error on name field and if address is entered and after that if i hit cancel, i'm invoking the action method "sampleBean.cancel"(to reset both name and address to blank) and then updating the form before hiding the dialog box.

However after hiding the dialog and if i click on ADD NEW again, Its still holding the old state(address value what i entered before).

My need is to clear and display the dialog without any old values.

Could someone point out the issue in my above code?

I'm using Primefaces 5.0

Found one solution to address it however i'm not sure if that's the right way to fix.

```
<p:commandButton value="Cancel" action="#{sampleBean.cancel}" immediate="true" oncomplete="PF('addDialog').hide()" update="addForm">
      <p:resetInput target="addForm"/>
</p:commandButton>
```

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

We have a similar dialog cancel button build up like this:

```
<p:commandButton value="#{bundle['common.action.cancel']}"
                 icon="#{bundle['common.icon.cancel']}"
                 action="#{bean.cancel}"
                 process="@this"
                 update="@none"
                 oncomplete="PF('dialog').hide();"/>
```

Where `bean.cancel` sets the dialog input values to `null` so we neither need further `process` nor `update` of other input elements.